# How do you inject the session for a unit test in ember-simple-auth?

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am unable to setup my unit test for an application route in my ember application.

Very simple route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {});
```

Very simple test:

```
import {
  moduleFor,
  test
} from 'ember-qunit';


import { authenticateSession } from '../../helpers/ember-simple-auth';

moduleFor('route:application', {
    beforeEach: function(){
        this.subject().set('session', authenticateSession);
    },
});

test('it exists', function(assert) {
  var route = this.subject();
  assert.ok(route);
});
```

I have tried several things, but they all throw the error:

```
Promise rejected before it exists: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '_this.get('session').on')
```

Which seems to indicate that the session is undefined in the mixin, anyone have unit tests working?  I could convert to a integration test, but would prefer to keep it as a unit level if possible.

Comment: have tried `session: inject.service(),` within your route?

Comment: Looked into the source that that is what was happening in the mixin, tried it anyway, but no affect.  Good thought though.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else runs into this it is just a "needs: ['service:session']" as found in a different answer here:

[EmberJS Service Injection for Unit Tests (Ember QUnit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125165/emberjs-service-injection-for-unit-tests-ember-qunit)